# CakePHP: display images, videos, audios, downloadable file outsite webroot folder

Tags: cakephp, router

in my project, i need move some files outside webroot folder (cause: security issues). but i dont know to config to display images, or downloadable file which was not resided in webroot folder.
Folder hierarchy:

- cms

  - app

    - webroot
    - **data_file**( images, videos, audios in here)

      - images
      - videos
      - audios

after upload a file to server successful , i need to save relative links point to the file in the database. with the above Folder hierarchy, how i save relative links format ? and display images(them) in the client

Answer (score 1):

Cakephp has media views built into the framework. You can serve up those files from a private filesystem location

```
public function download() {
    $this->viewClass = 'Media';
    // Download app/outside_webroot_dir/example.zip
    $params = array(
        'id'        => 'example.zip',
        'name'      => 'example',
        'download'  => true,
        'extension' => 'zip',
        'path'      => APP . 'outside_webroot_dir' . DS
    );
    $this->set($params);
}
```

Reference: [Media Views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html)

Your should first upload the file, then save the file name in the database. This assures you have the name of the file when wanting to access it from the media view. You should save the type of file (extension). This could be used in your business logic to decide if you want to force download the file or stream contents to the browser ('download' => false).

If you are using cake 2.3+ also consider [sending files](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cake-response-file)

Answer (score 0):

1. if you want to hide this folder from URL, you can take Sixthpoint's solution, I think.
2. if you just want to have another folder alternative to webroot, change .htaccess -

```
    
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
       RewriteRule    (\.png|\.jpg)$ app/your folder/images/$1
       RewriteRule    (\.mpg)$ app/your folder/videos/$1
       RewriteRule    (\.mp3)$ app/your folder/audios/$1
       RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

Any matched rule will be applied first. But I don't see this solution is better for your purpose.